# Radius of convergence for Maclaurin series for $\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to find a better way of doing this rather than differentiating and using the formula for the Maclaurin/Taylor series.

I noticed it's $$ 2x \cdot \frac{1}{1-\left( - x^2 \right)} $$
and so I can make this into a geometric sum multiplied by $2x$ $$ 2x \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( -x^2\right)^n $$

From here, I'd like to say the radius of convergence is $1$ since that is when $\left| -x^2 \right| <1$.

My question is, if this is right, why could I ignore that $2x$ multiplication? In other words, why does the above series have the same radius of convergence as this series $$ 2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} x^{2n+1}   $$ since shouldn't the $x$ be important, regardless of it being inside or outside of the summation?

Comment: A series $\sum b_n$ is convergent iff for any constant $c\neq 0$ the series $\sum (cb_n)$ is convergent. Apply this to $\sum a_nx^n$ and $x\neq 0.$

Answer (score 1):

One way is to compute both the two series and show they have the same convergent radius.

Another way is to think it as $f(x)\cdot\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( -x^2\right)^n $, where $f(x)=2x$, since $f(x)$ is a polynomial, so the convergent radius is determined by the rest part $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( -x^2\right)^n $